# What are the requirements to run a MonoGame game in Windows?

Tags: xna, monogame, requirements

If I developed a game in MonoGame, what are the requirements to run it on Windows?

Is the .NET Framework required? If so, what version should be installed?

Are there any other frameworks required?

Comment: Are you asking as a developer or user? Do you mean the requisites for playing a game someone developed, or for developing it?

Comment: @NahuelIanni i mean requirements for player who want to use  game that developed by monogame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements for running a MonoGame 3.4 game in Windows:

- .NET framework 4.X

For MonoGame Windows OpenGL:

- OpenGL 3.0 drivers
- OpenAL 1.1

For MonoGame Windows DirectX:

- DirectX 11 runtime

There's a post on the official forums which might help: [MonoGame minimum requirements](https://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/456254).

Comment: thank you. are you sure that OpenAL is needed? I hadn't heard of its role

Comment: I updated my answer. It's only required when you are using MonoGame Windows OpenGL assembly.